# Check if intent uri is available

Tags: android, android-intent, imdb

I have an app that sometimes links to imdb. I can do this with `http://m.imdb.com/find` or if it is available `imdb:///find`. My trouble is I can't find a way to check whether the `imdb://` is available before it is too late.

Because the link is clicked on by the user, I can't catch the `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException` exception.

Am I missing something obvious?

---

**Solution:**

By inazaruk's suggestion I'm now using the follwing code:

```
public static boolean isUriAvailable(Context context, String uri) {
    Intent test = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
    return context.getPackageManager().resolveActivity(test, 0) != null;
}
```

The method must be called with a direct uri to what you are requesting, like `imdb:///find` rather than just `imdb://`.

Comment: Is it possible to get data from the imdb activity? I mean, it could be great to get for example the rating of the movie, or somehting else.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`resolveActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#resolveActivity%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) to detect whether there is any `Activity` in the system capable of handling your intent. Of course you need to construct the intent that mimics the "uri" click. That might be done using [`Intent.setData()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setData%28android.net.Uri%29) function, though I didn't test/verify that myself.

Comment: I tried `Intent test = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("imdb://find"));` `getPackageManager().resolveActivity(test, 0);`, but it didn't even get a mention in the adb log.

Comment: It might not be mentioned in logs, its up to the implementation to decide. However you may add your own logs. Just print info returned in `ResolveInfo` instance from `resolveActivity()` yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was gonna throw an exception. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("imdb:///title/tt1457767/");
    intent.setData(uri);
    this.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

You can replace String in `Uri.parse("");`with any of followings:

```
            imdb:///name/<nameID>
            imdb:///find?q=<search_query>
            imdb:///title/<titleID>
            imdb:///boxoffice
            imdb:///name/<nameID>
            imdb:///find?q=toystory
```