# Android: exception is thrown when try to go to the store

Tags: android, exception, android-intent

My app has a button that leads (should lead, to be precise :) ) to another application's page in the GooglePlay. The button's click reaction is as follows:

```
public void pressedPurchaseButton(View view)
{
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.infmanrb.multrainer"));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
}
```

However, in emulator, button pressing causes an exception:

`Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.infmanrb.multrainer }`

I guess GooglePlay is not installed on Emulator - and that's the reason. But anyway, what is the correct way to avoid application crashing? Can I check in advance whether the Intent will be handled? Or the only way is to try-catch an exception?

Comment: indeed play is not installed on the emulator. to avoid crash you can either ask the content resolver of simply catch the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a utility method like this :

```
public static boolean isIntentHandleable(Context context, String action) {
    final PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    List<ResolveInfo> list =
        manager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return list.size() > 0;
}
```

Pass the intent that you want as action and ofcourse the context reference. If this returns false, this action cannot be handled.

Check this link as well : [Check if intent uri is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050068/check-if-intent-uri-is-available)